# NVelocity Issue

Tags: c#, nvelocity

I have taken over some work on an existing system that uses NVelocity templates. It iterates though some rows of data and then loops though the fields creating an html table of the data. I want to change this so that some of the table cells contains data from a different field.

here is how it works:

```
#if($data.Count > 0)
    #set ($end = $data.Count - 1)
    #foreach($count in [0 .. $end])
        <tr class="$!class $!alerts $!status">
        #set($colcount = 0)
        #foreach($field in $fields)
            <td class="$!colclass">
                $data.GetData($count, $field)
            </td>
        #end
        </tr>
    #end
#end
```

What I want it to do something like this :

```
#if($data.Count > 0)
    #set ($end = $data.Count - 1)
    #foreach($count in [0 .. $end])
        <tr class="$!class $!alerts $!status">
        #set($colcount = 0)
        #foreach($field in $fields)
            #if($field.Name=="JourneyAlias")
                $data.GetData($count, $field) - $data.GetData($count, 'JourneyId')
            #else
                <td class="$!colclass">
                    $data.GetData($count, $field)
                </td>
            #end
        #end
        </tr>
    #end
#end
```

In short I want to know how to access the field JourneyId from the data

Comment: What are the types of $data and $fields?

Comment: Sorted the issue I needed this syntax: #set($journeyid = $data.DataItem($count).JourneyID)

Comment: you can answer your own question and after a couple of days accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue I needed this syntax:

```
#set($journeyid = $data.DataItem($count).JourneyID)
```